# How to load csv with nested columns using Apache Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file:

```
name,age,phonenumbers
Tom,20,"[{number:100200, area_code:555},{number:100300, area_code:444}]"
Harry,20,"[{number:100400, area_code:555},{number:100500, area_code:666}]"
```

How can I load this file in Spark to a RDD/Dataset of Person where Person object looks like:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    List<Phone> phonenumbers;

    class Phone {
        int number;
        int area_code; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried Encoders.bean<Person.class>. This works in above case but my bean has Map in it as a result I get "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: map type is not supported currently"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the column names for the nested object don't have quotes in your example. Is that truly the case? Because if they DO have quotes (e.g. well-formed JSON) then you could very easily use the `from_json` function as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = new ArrayType(new StructType()
  .add("number", IntegerType)
  .add("area_code", IntegerType), false)

val converted = input.withColumn("phones", from_json('phonenumbers, schema))
```

If that's not the case, then you'll need to use your own logic to convert the string into the actual nested object, such as:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Phone(number: Int, area_code:Int)

case class Person(name: String, age: Int, phonenumbers: Array[Phone])

val converted = input.map {
  case Row(name: String, age: Int, phonenumbers: String) => {
    import scala.util.matching.Regex
    val phoneFormat = raw"\{number:(\d{6}), area_code:(\d{3})\}".r
    val phones = for (m <- phoneFormat.findAllMatchIn(phonenumbers)) yield Phone(m.group(1).toInt, m.group(2).toInt)
    Person(name, age, phones.toArray)
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like I need to go with second approach of manually constructing Person object